# Flutter Invalid reference to "this" expression issue in Card

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is my widget Card code.

I have Invalid reference to "this" expression issue here "this.tdbucreti = value;"

How can I fix that? thanks for help.

String tdbucreti;

```
 Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context , data) {

  return Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
  elevation: 5,
  child: ExpansionCard(


    title: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TDB Ücreti'),
          onChanged: (value) {
            this.tdbucreti = value;
          },
        ),

         Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 1),
              child: Text(data['anlasilantutar'],
                style:  GoogleFonts.montserrat(color: Colors.blueGrey[700], fontSize: 20 , textStyle: 
            TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),


          ],
        ),
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable is in the class which does not contain `buildResultCard`, your class's closing parentheses are above the `buildResultCard`.

```
} //your class finishes here
Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context , data) {

  return Card(
```

wrap `buildResultCard` with above class's closing parentheses like this:

```
Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context , data) {

  return Card(....)
 } //your class finishes here
```

for this reason your function can't see class's varibales